# Show that if $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices and $x$ and $y$ are two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then…

Tags: linear-algebra

> Show that if $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices and $x$ and $y$ are two vectors in $R^n$ then the scalar product of $Ax$ and $By$ is the same as the scalar product of $x$ and $(A^TB)y$.

I'm really bad at showing or proving a general statement. Tips or examples on how I should proceed would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the scalar product of $x$ and $y$ is defined as
$$
x^Ty
$$
so the scalar product of $Ax$ and $By$ is
$$
(Ax)^T(By)=(x^T A^T) (By)
$$
Then…

Comment: Ah I see, it's much clearer now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: You can write the scalar product $\langle u,v\rangle$ of $u$ and $v$ as $u^\top v$. So you get the fundamental and useful property: $\langle Cx,y \rangle = \langle x,C^\top y\rangle$.